# React use form for img radio buttons

Tags: reactjs, forms, image, radio-button

I am trying to create a rock, paper and scissor game in react. I would assume that it makes sense to use a form for this, I would atleast use a form haven't it been for react.

I figured that the simplest way of doing this, would be three radio inputs and a submit.

However, since I want to use three pictures as the actual radio buttons. Would it even make sense to use a form since react aims to take the state out of the form. This is the point in my code where i realized that I might be on a sidetrack.

```
   onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <form>
            <input type="radio" value="Rock" name="gender" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} /> Rock
            <input type="radio" value="Paper" name="gender" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} /> Paper
            <input type="radio" value="Scissor" name="gender" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} /> Scissor
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick = () => {submit()}/>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img id="r" value="rock" src="http://www.jerrylow.com/demo/rps/rock.svg" alt="a rock" />
          <img id="p" value="paper" src="http://www.jerrylow.com/demo/rps/paper.svg" alt="a piece of paper" />
          <img id="s" value="scissor" src="http://www.jerrylow.com/demo/rps/scissor.svg" alt="a scissor" />
        </div>)
  }
```

Should I use this form, even though the form serves no particular purpose. If yes, how should i integrate it with the img elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few ways of going about it. You can forgo the form entirely and attach `onClick` listeners to each of the images that would modify the state when clicked and then have a button that when clicked would call your submit function.

Or, if you wish to retain the form, you could either wrap the radio buttons and images in labels, hide the radio buttons such that when the image is clicked, it would trigger the `onChange`. Or, you could specify a `for` prop on the label that matches the id of a radio button and have the image in that and it would behave as the previously described, something like

```
<input type="radio" id="myButton" onChange={handleChange} />
<label for="myButton"><img src="img.png" /></label>
```

I guess it really comes down to the solution you want because either way would be fine. I would personally prefer not using a form for this scenario purely because it's not that necessary and the code would be smaller.

Comment: Roger that, makes sense. Thanks for your time!